# When I go back, the page does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I have a webpage with filterrific to create search criterias and recently it has started to make some annoying errors.

When I make a search with some criterias and click on one of the results and want to return back to the page with all the results, the url changes, but I'm still on the same page.

[Here is a video to display the problem](https://youtu.be/ZkInlULH4FI)

Does this seem familiar to anyone? I do not know what code to include, since I have no idea was is causing the problem and since it used to be working, but if you have any suggestions, I will add the code!

[Here is a link to the webpage, if you would like to test it yourself](http://www.rentapart.dk/apartments)

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```
// Search criteria in the url
var ready = function(){
$("#filterrific_filter").click(function(){
  $.get($("#filterrific_filter").attr("action"), $("#filterrific_filter").serialize(), null, "script");
  history.pushState(null, document.title, $("#filterrific_filter").attr("action") + "?" + $("#filterrific_filter").serialize());
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
  $.getScript(location.href);
});
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Turns out this is the source of the problem. This puts the search criterias into the url, to be able to copy and paste a specific search. If I remove it, it works. Any help?

Comment: I'm noticing a few things. 1) if I don't select any search criteria and just click one of the images it works fine. 2) If I do select search criteria and hit the back button, I see the failure, but if I click 2 *more* times, it takes me back to the search view.  I guess it would be good to see the view code for the building of the images, any javascript (if there is any) that is used either when preparing the image or clicking the image. Perhaps the controller code for the search and for the get of the single item view?

Comment: I have updated the post with the code that causes the problem.